# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: powershell

How do I get the current path of the currently executing command or script?

Tried the following script:

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
write-host $scriptpath
```

and calling it like so:

```
 invoke-command -computername localhost -filepath .\test.ps1
```

Also tried the following but get a blank line:

```
invoke-command -scriptblock { write-host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path }
```

Comment: answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5220517/520612

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get script directory in PowerShell when script is invoked with Invoke-Command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219461/get-script-directory-in-powershell-when-script-is-invoked-with-invoke-command)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using $pwd for getting the path?